# Apache Automatic Virtual Host set up on OSX

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I have multiple projects which I would like to server using an Apache `VirtualDocumentRoot` setup [using Apache's `mod_vhost_alias` module](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html) such that each project has it's own domain name. As an example:

- `http://site1.local` resides in `/Users/stu/Sites/Project1/site1_app/`
- `http://prox.local` resides in `/Users/stu/Sites/AlphaProX/prox_app/`

I have about 20 entries like this and I was curious to know if I can have this setup. I currently have this VirtualHost entry that is not working:

```
<Virtualhost *:80>
    VirtualDocumentRoot "/Users/stu/Sites/*/%1/"
    ServerName vhosts.local
    ServerAlias *.local
    UseCanonicalName Off
    LogFormat "%V %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %s %b" vcommon
    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/vhosts-error_log"
    <Directory "/Users/stu/Sites/*">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</Virtualhost>
```

Where is my syntax wrong?

Comment: @AngelS.Moreno The question may be on topic for Server Fault, but it is at best ambiguous. You seem to want something, but you do a poor job describing *what* you want. [If you take some time to improve your question to meet our quality standards](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3608/how-can-i-ask-better-questions-on-server-fault) it may get reopened. Remember, we no *nothing except what you tell us*...

Comment: thank you for the advice. I took it. please review the question now.

Comment: If I didn't change your question with my edits, the answer is "You can't, because of the `Project1` directory"

Comment: Brilliant answer. symlinking is the way to get what i want!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, as it is you can't do this because there is no way for Apache to determine the `Project1` or `AlphaProX` part of the path name.

These strings must either be in the URL, or, they must not be in the path. It would work if the paths were like `/Users/stu/Sites/prox/prox_app/` because now the variable string `prox` is used. But otherwise Apache has no idea to look under `AlphaProX/`, your `VirtualDocumentRoot "/Users/stu/Sites/*` line won't work. (Apache is literally looking for a directory named `*/`)

You can make this work if you create a directory like `/Users/stu/Sites/vhost_aliases` and create *symbolic links* under that directory to the actual projects, EG:

```
mkdir -p /Users/stu/Sites/vhost_aliases
cd /Users/stu/Sites/vhost_aliases
ln -s ../site1_app
ln -s ../AlphaProX/prox_app
```

Then, you'll want your `httpd.conf` file to look like:

```
<Virtualhost *:80>
    VirtualDocumentRoot "/Users/stu/Sites/vhost_aliases/%1_app/"
    ServerName vhosts.local
    ServerAlias *.local
    UseCanonicalName Off
    LogFormat "%V %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %s %b" vcommon
    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/vhosts-error_log"
    <Directory "/Users/stu/Sites/vhost_aliases">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</Virtualhost>
```

Specifically, this line:

```
VirtualDocumentRoot "/Users/stu/Sites/vhost_aliases/%1_app/"
```